# Searching text containing spaces inside sql Select statement

Tags: sql, hana

I want to search for multiple names inside the column name using a single `Select` statement

Ex:`abc xyz`, `qpr srt` and the names match must be exact

How I can implement this in SQL?

Comment: if my answer is not right, please give the example like what's the table look like and whats the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause and OR condition

```
select * from employee where name='abc xyz' or name='qpr srt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [contains predicate](https://help.sap.com/viewer/DRAFT/05c9edaee7fe4d28ab3627d0b1583df6/dev/en-US/9a4da8f6f23b4ebf95c98f1104a56db4.html?q=contains%20predicate) might help.

```
select * from employee 
where CONTAINS(your_full_name_column, 'abc AND xyz')
```

You could also implement fuzzy search or partial matches and have the returned rows sorted by relevance with the score() function.